# Building a Classification model for predicting Customer Churn

Tags: logistic, classification, cart, naive-bayes, churn

I am currently building a Customer Churn Prediction model and the project is in the process of development of models. The client has given data till Sep 2019 and wants to check if the model is able to correctly predict the customers who are likely to churn. The target variable is 0-> customer is still active and 1-> customer is inactive and has churned.

Now the client wants us to predict the likely churn customers (on data given till Sep 2019) and wants to check if the model was able to correctly predict. The validation will be done based on Data from Sep to Dec where the client has determined a list of customers who were active till Sep 2019 and have now left/churned in Dec 2019.

While our accuracies/Precision/Recall are good and acceptable, we are finding it difficult to correctly predict the customers who have become 1 in Dec 2019 from 0 in Sep 2019.